You are using npm 2.15.12 so the project will be bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools. On Mac, see windows solutions but I need a mac
You are using npm 2.15.12 so the project will be bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools. On Mac, see windows solutions but I need a mac
I am using the latest version of npm v10.9.1, node v20.10.0 nvm v0.38.0
what am I missing? I had even tried to nvm use 10.9.1 and it says it isn't installed? Also tried
npx create-react-app@latest moon-fairies --use-npm
sudo chown -R 501:80 "/Users/jlj/.npm

I still can't get npx create-react-app to work, I had used this for years, took 5 months off now it doesn't work. I have read the other articles in here and still have not found a solution, I would really appreciate some help if anyone on a Mac has solved this or struggled

ok, I did this npx -p npm@10.9.1 create-react-app my-app
and it worked but it isn't a full fix...
